# How to use postman for saving object?

Tags: c#, json, rest, postman

I am able to use Postman exposed methods by posting by json object. But when I am trying saving object I dont know how to use it in Postman.

example:

> htt://domain.com/P_DataServices/Data.svc/AddCommitteeMembers

`AddCommitteeMembers` is method so I can pass json

```
{
    "CommitteeMasterCustomerId":"9980001",
    "CommitteeSubCustomerId":0,
    "CommitteeMembers":[{
        ...
        ...
    }]
}
```

it works fine.

by using C# code I use like this for exposed methods `AddCommitteeMembersOutput output = SvcClient.Client.Post<AddCommitteeMembersOutput>("AddCommitteeMembers", MembersInput);`

But when object like `CusActivity` and trying save into `htt://domain.com/P_DataServices/Data.svc` I don't know how to use it in postman chrome application.

But using C# code I can save object like this
`CusActivity oRespSave = SvcClient.Client.Save<CusActivity>(oRespCreate);`

How to use postman for this case to save object?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question, I have a hard time trying to figure out what you are trying to do? Perhaps [this](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service)

Comment: @ChadPeruggia can try to understand now? I can write C# code and directly object calling service. But testing purpose how to use Postman in this case?